# Keep selected tab when click on back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is the demo code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".advertising" class="button"> ADVERTISING </a></li>  
</ul>
```

suppose, advertise is selected and and goes inside it. Clicking on back button sends back to All tab selected, how to get advertise selected.

I tried following codes but doesn't work

```
<a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Back</a>
<button type="button" onclick="history.back();">Back</button>
```

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313270/jquery-ui-tabs-no-longer-supporting-cookie-now-what/14313315#14313315`

Comment: `selected tab` which plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should send back the `data-filter` from the inside page to identify which tab needs to be selected.

If received `.advertising` data-filter then you need to add class `is-checked` to the respective `<a>` tag

**Example**

**Inside page**

```
<a href="mainPage.php?dataFilter=.advertising">Back</a>
```

don't forget to update the filename `mainPage.php` to your file name

**Main page**

```
<?php
    $dataFilter = $_GET['dataFilter'];
?>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="button<?php echo ($dataFilter=='*' || $dataFilter=='')?" is-checked":""; ?>" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".advertising" class="button<?php echo ($dataFilter=='.advertising')?" is-checked":""; ?>"> ADVERTISING </a></li>  
</ul>
```