# Remember last tab after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a complex view on Laravel with a lot of tabs and forms, the user can navigate on the tabs and do various form submits on every tab, after the submit the controllers returns the same view with a current tab variable, looks like this:

```
...Controller actions...

return view("store.tesla.user.components")
                ->with('tab', '3');
```

Every tab got an ID so when I go back to my view I just search for the active tab and put active with jQuery like this:

```
var tb_active = <?php echo $tab; ?>
$('#'+tb_active).addClass('active');
```

Actually it works, but I feel dirty mixing PHP+JS specially using Laravel framework and looks not so well done, so there are my question/s:

**There is another way to do it better or more simple?**

My view is extremly big and I have a lot of css classes, if I copy my code there it will be messy, so I fork a codepen with bootstrap tabs for better showing :)

https://codepen.io/Troyer/pen/MbGQPJ

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"><h1>Bootstrap  tab panel example (using nav-pills)  </h1></div>
<div id="exTab1" class="container"> 
<ul  class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active">
        <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix</a>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

            <div class="tab-content clearfix">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
          <h3>Content's background color is the same for the tab</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
          <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
                </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">
          <h3>We applied clearfix to the tab-content to rid of the gap between the tab and the content</h3>
                </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="4a">
          <h3>We use css to change the background color of the content to be equal to the tab</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  padding : 10px ;

}

#exTab1 .tab-content {
  color : white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding : 5px 15px;
}

#exTab2 h3 {
  color : white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding : 5px 15px;
}

/* remove border radius for the tab */

#exTab1 .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}

/* change border radius for the tab , apply corners on top*/

#exTab3 .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0 ;
}

#exTab3 .tab-content {
  color : white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding : 5px 15px;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you have forms in each tab, then u know which form is for which tab, so u can pass the tab id, from controller itself, and use ur above js code. But if every tab does not have forms, then i guess what u r doing is correct and only way.

Comment: @Purushottamzende There are some tabs only with information. I'm happy if it's the correct way then. :)

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313270/jquery-ui-tabs-no-longer-supporting-cookie-now-what/14313315#14313315)

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Oh wow, a hidden input (I will use a div with data) would be a nice solution because I can persist the current tab selected there. Nice one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried hidden fields. You can set that tab active by read that hidden value like:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ active: $('#your-hidden-fiel').val() });
```

See the [full example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313270/jquery-ui-tabs-no-longer-supporting-cookie-now-what/14313315#14313315).

Answer (score 1):

create an array in js below your content section

```
var pagedefaults = {
        activetab: "{{ $activetab }}",
};
```

Here `$activetab` is coming from your controller. Now you can use active tab value like `pagedefaults.activetab` in your javascript and make tab active.
This can also be used in localisation and Ajax Routes.